# PayPal Express Checkout with debit card throws error in sandbox environment

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I just integrated the [PayPal Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/) for my shopping cart with basic client integration. I used the sandbox environment for integration testing and everything works well if the sandbox test account ("PERSONAL") of the sandbox environment has either a positive PayPal balance or a credit card deposited to the sandbox test account.

But if the sandbox test account has only a debit card deposited, then it is not possible to charge the PayPal account, I receive following error due to `actions.payment.execute()` in the `onAuthorize` callback:

`POST https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/.../createpayment - 400 Bad Request`
with JSON response field *contingency* set to `PAYMENT_NOT_APPROVED_FOR_EXECUTION`.

I am using exactly the same JavaScript code for my application as in the [basic client integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/) example provided by PayPal, I just changed the 'env' to sandbox and edited my sandbox API key. I am wondering why this error is thrown when using debit card as payment method since I know from private use of PayPal that it is possible to pay with PayPal deposited debit card directly. Or is this just a sandbox specific error?